# Std in ndk with cpp - vector problems

Tags: c++, stl, vector, android-ndk

I am trying to compile a large c++ code for ndk.

I get a bunch of errors. A lot of them related to vectors:

- `vector<int> myvector` --> the '`<`' gives an error
- `::iterator` cannot be declared

Any ideas on how to get full STL support? I use a lot of libraries, like vector, algorithm, iostream etc

Here is my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := vns.cpp note.cpp cscore.cpp hscorecf.cpp hscorecp.cpp scoreinfo.cpp cscore.cpp score.cpp randMusic.cpp input.cpp main.cpp

APP_STL := stlport_shared
#but I have tried system, stlport_static, stlport_shared, or gnustl_static.
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Got it.

I needed to put APP_STL := stlport_shared in a separate Application.mk file!

Comment: Have you tried `std::vector<int> myvector` (with the `std::`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I needed to put APP_STL := stlport_shared in a separate Application.mk file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to `#include <vector>` header or `using namespace std;`

Comment: `using namespace std` is, more often than not, a bad idea.

Comment: Got it. 

I needed to put APP_STL := stlport_shared in a separate Application.mk file.